# ArrayList.get(int) on a null object reference - Android

Tags: android

#### Error:

```
Error : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mpmusic, PID: 10142
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mpmusic/com.example.mpmusic.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mpmusic.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:90)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

#### `PlayerActivity`:

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnPlay , btnNext , btnPrevious , btnForward , btnRewind;
    TextView txtSongName , txtSongStart , txtSongEnd;
    SeekBar seekMusicBar;

    ImageView imageView;

    String songName;
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "song_name";
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int position;
    ArrayList<File> mySongs;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    Thread updateSeekBar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nhac Viet");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        btnPrevious = findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
        btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        btnForward = findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
        btnRewind = findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);

        txtSongName = findViewById(R.id.txtSong);
        txtSongStart = findViewById(R.id.txtSongStart);
        txtSongEnd = findViewById(R.id.txtSongEnd);

        seekMusicBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        if(mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        mySongs = (ArrayList)bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
        String sName = intent .getStringExtra("songname");
        position = bundle.getInt("pos",0);
        txtSongName.setSelected(true);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
        songName = mySongs.get(position).getName();
        txtSongName.setText(songName);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
        mediaPlayer.start();


        updateSeekBar = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                int currentPosition = 0;

                while(currentPosition<totalDuration)
                {
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                        currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        seekMusicBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    super.run();
                }

            }
        };

        seekMusicBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        updateSeekBar.start();
        seekMusicBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_700),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        seekMusicBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_700), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);


        seekMusicBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                      mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });


        String endTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        txtSongEnd.setText(endTime);

        final Handler handle = new Handler();
        final int delay = 1000;

        handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String currentTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                txtSongStart.setText(currentTime);
                handle.postDelayed(this,delay);
            }
        },delay);

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                else
                {
                    btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                    TranslateAnimation moveAnim = new TranslateAnimation(-25,-25,-25,-25);
                    moveAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    moveAnim.setDuration(600);
                    moveAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
                    moveAnim.setFillAfter(true);
                    moveAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
                    moveAnim.setRepeatCount(1);
                    imageView.startAnimation(moveAnim);
                }
            }
        });



        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                btnNext.performClick();
            }
        });




        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mediaPlayer.stop();
               mediaPlayer.release();
               position = (position+1)%mySongs.size();
               Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
               mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
               songName = mySongs.get(position).getName();
               txtSongName.setText(songName);
               mediaPlayer.start();

               startAnimation(imageView,360f);
            }
        });
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                position = ((position-1)<0)?(mySongs.size()-1):position-1;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);
                songName = mySongs.get(position).getName();
                txtSongName.setText(songName);
                mediaPlayer.start();


                startAnimation(imageView,-360f);
            }
        });


        btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+10000);
                }
            }
        });

        btnRewind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()-10000);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String createTime(int duration) {
        String time = "";
        int min = duration/1000/60;
        int sec = duration/1000%60;

        time = time+min+":";
        if(sec<10){
            time+="0";
        }
        return time;
    }


    public void startAnimation(View view , Float degree){
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,"rotation",0f,degree);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playTogether(objectAnimator);
        animatorSet.start();
    }
```

#### `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        runtimePermission();
    }

    public void runtimePermission() {
        Dexter.withContext(this).withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport multiplePermissionsReport) {
                        displaySong();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

    }
    public ArrayList<File> findSong(File  file){
        ArrayList<File> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        File[] files = file.listFiles();

        for(File singleFile : files){
            if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden())
            {
                arrayList.addAll(findSong(singleFile));
            }
            else
            {
                if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav"))
                {
                    arrayList.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

    public void displaySong()
    {
        final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        items = new String[mySongs.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<mySongs.size();i++)
        {
            items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".wav","");
        }

        customAdapter customAdapter = new customAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>  parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String songName = (String)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayerActivity.class)
                 .putExtra("song",mySongs)
                        .putExtra("songname",songName)
                        .putExtra("pos",position)
                );

            }
        });

    }

    class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            TextView txtSong = view.findViewById(R.id.txtSong);
            txtSong.setSelected(true);
            txtSong.setText(items[position]);
            return view;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004) and if you still haven't solved your problem, show code & android manifest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My PlayerActivity :

Answer (score 0):

#### **Problem:**

The song list you're trying to use in `PlayerActivity` is null.

#### **Reason:**

You're sending the Songs' list using `Intent` Extras but here's the catch.

You're putting the list as an extra with key `song` in `MainActivity`. But, you're trying to get the extra with key `songs` in `PlayerActivity`.

#### **Solution:**

Change your `MainActivity` code from

```
.putExtra("song",mySongs)
```

to

```
.putExtra("songs",mySongs)
```

Alternatively, You can change `songs` to `song` in `PlayerActivity`, the endgame is just the keys should match otherwise you're reading null data.